# Ignoring fields when deserialising with lift-json in Scala

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

How does I deserialise data like [this](http://pastebin.com/PwTN7F5J) into a case class like this:

```
case class SoundCloudUser (
  id: Int,
  permalink: String,
  username: String,
  country: String,
  full_name: String,
  city: String,
  description: String)
```

(that is, where the case class has less constructor arguments than the JSON has values)

I tried creating a FieldSerializer to do this, but I could only work out how to ignore fields when serialising, not deserialising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the fields in the JSON data are a superset of the fields in your case class, you don't need to do anything special to ignore the fields in the JSON data that aren't in your case class. It should "just work". Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hmmm. I was. Clearly it was something else. The error I was receiving was 

  "net.liftweb.json.MappingException: Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor"  

although now I'm not...